# Using Python (Selenium) to Scrape IMDB (.click() is not working)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrape

I am trying to scrape a list of specific movies from IMDB using this [tutorial](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/movie-recommendation-from-imdb-reviews-without-actually-read-the-reviews-fe8865a70bd5).

The code is working fine expect for the for **click** to get the URL then saves in content. It is not working. The issue is that nothing change in chrome when running the code I really appreciate if anyone can help.

```
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tF2Cxc").click()
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import time

movie = 'Wolf Totem'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\chromedriver.exe")

#Go to Google
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

#Enter the keyword
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(movie + " imdb")
time.sleep(1)

#Click the google search button
driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Whay you mean by "not working"? Does it give you any error traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong locator.
To open the a search result on Google page you should use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='yuRUbf']/a").click()
```

This locator will match all the 10 search results, so the first match is the first search result.
Also, clicking on that element will not give you any content, just open the first link below the title of the first search result.

Comment: Thank you @Prophet. it is working very well. When printing the content, it does not content the URL.